# Junit 5 with rest api (get all)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, rest

I'm learning junit 5 for rest api.

Unit test for get method (get all instance) and this my code.

my data

```
[{"id":1,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},
{"id":2,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},
{"id":3,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},
{"id":4,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},
{"id":5,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},
{"id":6,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6}]
```

ExampleController

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @Autowired
    MExampleRepository mExampleRepository;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(name = "name", defaultValue = "World")  String name) {
        return String.format("Hello, %s", name);
    }

    /**
     * get all
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<MExample> getAll() {
        return mExampleRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

ExampleControllerTest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ExampleControllerIntTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private MExampleRepository mExampleRepository;

    @Test
    void testHelloWithName() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/hello?name=Dan"))
                .andExpect(content().string("Hello, Dan"));
    }

    //junit test

    //get all example

    @Test
    void getAll() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = get("/");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());

        Object lExamples = mExampleRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(lExamples, result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

and then result when run test

```
Expected :[MExample(id=1, example2=2, example3=3, example4=4, example5=5, example6=6), MExample(id=2, example2=2, example3=3, example4=4, example5=5, example6=6), MExample(id=3, example2=2, example3=3, example4=4, example5=5, example6=6), MExample(id=4, example2=2, example3=3, example4=4, example5=5, example6=6), MExample(id=5, example2=2, example3=3, example4=4, example5=5, example6=6), MExample(id=6, example2=2, example3=3, example4=4, example5=5, example6=6)]
Actual   :[{"id":1,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},{"id":2,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},{"id":3,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},{"id":4,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},{"id":5,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6},{"id":6,"example2":2,"example3":3,"example4":4,"example5":5,"example6":6}]
```

I want it pass for this test but i dont known what to do.

Sorry if the question is not clear, my english is a bit bad

Anyone help me, thank you.

Comment: Do you have a `maven` project?  If so, it would help to paste your `pom.xml` file here.  Also, be careful with the `SpringRunner` plus Junit5.  Probably you can pull it off, but you need to have the right set up in your project.  For JUnit5, I use the test harness from "junit-jupiter", and specifically, `@SpringJUnitWebConfig` along with `MockMvc`.

Comment: @KodeCharlie yep, i use maven. Is there a way to make the expect the same as the actual or vice versa? i dont know convert it.

Comment: i try replace SpringRunner with SpringJunitWebConfig, but error
is still the same

Comment: I just did this, it's ok, but I don't know if it's the right test standard
`    
@Test
    void getAll() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = get("/");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());

        Object lExamples = mExampleRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(new Gson().toJson(lExamples), result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json doesn't store objects inside content. In this case, you store MExample in database but spring boot help you to convert object to json in http response.
You have 3 methods to solve this problem:

1. Convert lExamples to Json, use toString() method to make comparison

```html
Object lExamples = mExampleRepository.findAll();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(lExamples);
assertEquals(json.toString(), result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
```

2. Install your data without using Object
3. Convert Http response to List object

Comment: thank you! I don't enough 15 reputation so I can't up vote.

Comment: @Manh you can mark it a correct answer.